# What does ajax do to JSF inputtext?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have an input textbox that accept a name, process the name in reverse order, and then output it to another textbox. Whenever I input the value and click anywhere on the page (means lost focus from textbox), the output textbox will get update automatically.

When I open up the source code I found something like code below, may I know what does the ajax thing do to the inputtext component?

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name}">
  <f:ajax render="printMyName"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:outputText id="printMyName" value="#{helloBean.reverseName}"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Taken from [Learning JSF2: Ajax in JSF – using f:ajax tag](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/)

> Sending an Ajax request
>
> JSF comes with one tag to send an Ajax request, the tag is called
>   f:ajax. This tag is actually a client side behavior. Being a behavior
>   implies it’s never just used by itself on a page, it is always added
>   as a child tag (behavior) to another UI component (or can even wrap
>   several components). Let’s use a small echo application to demonstrate
>   usage of this tag.

```
<h:form> 
  <h:panelGrid> 
      <h:inputText value="#{bean.text}" > 
         <f:ajax event="keyup" render="text"/> 
      </h:inputText> 
      <h:outputText id="text" value="#{bean.text}" /> 
   </h:panelGrid> 
</h:form>
```

> Code snippet above takes care of firing an Ajax request based on onkeyup event. Notice the actual event name is keyup. This takes care of firing an Ajax request. Next we need to figure out how to do partial view rendering.

**Attribute Description event:**

> String on which event Ajax request will be
>   fired. If not specified, a default behavior based on parent component
>   will be applied. The default event is action for ActionSource (ie:
>   button) components and valueChange for EditableValueHolder components
>   (ie: input). action and valueChange are actual String values that can
>   be applied applied event attribute.

Comment: can I add ajax programmatically? I am making my custom input filed by extending HtmlInputText. I want to know when value change occurs. It would be very helpful.

Comment: If you are extending an existing component which already have ajax then you will ajax in your extended component as well, any way you better ask a new question